# Prove that $\frac{n^n}{(n + 1)^n}$ converges to $\frac{1}{e}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

Using the [formal definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_of_a_sequence#Formal_definition) of sequence limits, I would like to prove that for:

$$
   a_n := \frac{n^n}{(n + 1)^n}
$$

it is:

$$
   \lim_{n\to\infty} a_n = \frac{1}{e}.
$$

Thus, it remains to show that:

$$
   \left|a_n - a\right| < \varepsilon\; \forall n \geq n_0
$$

Using the triangle inequality, it follows that,
    \begin{align*}
    \left| a_n - a \right| = \left| \frac{n^n}{(n + 1)^n} - \frac{1}{e} \right| = & \left| \frac{n^n \cdot e + (-(n + 1)^n)}{(n + 1)^n \cdot e} \right| \\
    \leq & \left| \frac{n^n \cdot e }{(n + 1)^n \cdot e} \right| + \left| - \frac{1}{e} \right|\\
    = & \left| \frac{n^n}{(n + 1)^n} \right| + \frac{1}{e}\\
    = & \left| a_n \right| + \frac{1}{e}
\end{align*}

But that's where I struggle; that didn't show anything that I didn't know beforehand, did it? I feel like I've moved in a circle.

Could someone point out what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: What is your definition of $e$?

Comment: What is the definition of $e$ in use?

Comment: @user60589 [This](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E_(mathematical_constant)#History) is the definition in use.

Comment: @chiru Use that both limits exist and show that their product converges to 1.

Comment: Hint: Re-write $\dfrac{n}{n + 1} = 1 - \dfrac{1}{n + 1}$.

Comment: look at $\frac{1}{a_n}$, since the sequence stays away from zero. If it converges to $e$ then $a_n$ converges to $\frac{1}{e}$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Observe that

$$\frac n{n+1}=\frac1{1+\frac1n}\implies\frac {n^n}{(1+n)^n}=\left(\frac n{1+n}\right)^n=\left(\frac1{1+\frac1n}\right)^n=$$

$$=\frac1{\left(1+\frac1n\right)^n}\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}\frac1e$$

by arithmetic of limits.